# Problema al virtualizar android studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Cuando presiono play para iniciar el emulador arranca muestra unos segundos el dispositivo luego lo cierra y muesta en una ventana emergente e
The emulator process for AVD Nexus_6_API_R was killed.

Comment: que mensaje de error se muestra en la consola de Android Studio? ahí debe mostrar algún mensaje para saber cual es el problema de otra forma con la información que comentas pueden ser diversas las causas, revisa por favor [ask], saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias, encontré la solución en aplicaciones y características de Windows se debe activar el Hyper-V